# Analog input to the PI

Tags: gpio, hardware, i2c, serial

I have a bit of a specialized question for you. Recently I got my Pi up and running, and am amazed at what it can pull off. But I want more.

I want to be able to record the output from an accelerometer, which is recording aspects of an impact. To do so I will need a minimum of a **12 bit ADC sampling at 100 kHz**. At that speed I figure I will need an **external microcontroller to buffer the samples**, and then have the Pi read in from the buffer to do all of its fun UI stuff. I am planning on using SPI to let them all chat, but am open to suggestions.

Now the kicker is I can only use **DIP packages** since I do not have PCB abilities. Could someone suggest a microcontroller and ADC that could handle this? I would prefer if there were no expensive programmers required, gotta love the open source theme with the Pi.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions!

Comment: If you need 100MHz sampling you are probably looking at something that costs a good bit more than the Raspberry Pi.  And as soon as you add the requirement that it is a DIP I think you are searching for something that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks Craig for the reply, good to know that they dont make something in a DIP package that will do that.

Comment: *100kHz* is much different. My comment only applied if you needed MHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a [MCP3008](https://www.adafruit.com/products/856) may be exactly what you want. The datasheet claims up to 200 ksps at 5 Volts.

In fact there is a [tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/send-raspberry-pi-data-to-cosm) about using this with a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Craig. That is a great starting point. I'll be writing the code in Java or C, but it should be fairly analogous.

Comment: Just note that the MCP3008 is 10 bit resolution and you said you needed a minimum of 12 bits.

Answer (score 1):

100kHz is very much easier than 100MHz!

You could try an [ADC121S021](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc121s021.pdf) or an [ADS7822](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ads7822)

Comment: Perfect! I suspect I'll need a microcontroller to buffer the output from the ADC as well? I dont think the Pi will be able to keep up if it is running a UI.

Comment: @user1003131, Not sure. If you are using spidev the kernel probably does some buffering for you. You should report back here with your findings.

Comment: Sounds good, will do!

Answer (score 0):

the lack of pcb abilities can be easily compensated with abundance of pcb fab houses on the internet, that not only manufacture, but also assemble your design for a small price.

other than that, you're out of luck. 12bit (16bit w/padding) @ 100Mhz is about 200MB/sec of data you have to process, the Raspberry Pi will *NOT* be able to do that no matter how many external microcontrollers you attach to it.

Comment: I factored in the padding into the 12 bit, but understand where your coming from. I did mean to say 100 kHz, but it is still quite a bit of data. I only need to capture for a 10 second interval if that makes any difference.